# Java string[] to string[]

Tags: java, arrays, string, pointers, copy

I'm getting `java.lang.NullPointerException`, but I don't know why.

```
private String[] fileInfo;

public void createPartControl(Composite parent){
   ...

   setFileInfo( "MyFile.log" );
}

private void setFileInfo(String file){
   String[] temp = file.split("\\.");
   fileInfo[0] = temp[0];
   fileInfo[1] = temp[1];

   System.out.println(temp[0]); // OK
   System.out.println(temp[1]); // OK
   System.out.println(fileInfo[0]); // ERROR
   System.out.println(fileInfo[1]); // ERROR
}
```

Comment: `fileInfo[]` is `null` because you didn't assign an instance of an arary into it. This is not like in C, array is strictly a reference type. Do note that even in C your code would be broken because you never specify the size of `fileInfo[]`.

Comment: Are you sure there is no error 3 lines before the print? Where the assignment to the array element is made?

Answer (score 2):

`fileInfo` array need to be initialized.

```
String[] fileInfo = new String[temp.length];
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize

```
private String[] fileInfo;
```

of your class as shown below

```
public Test(){ // Constructor of the class
    fileInfo = new String[10]; // here 10 is taken as any constant
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have not initialized `fileInfo`.

Write:

`String[] fileInfo = new String[100];`

and your code will not work. But you have to decide the array length (10) in this case). You can do better. Why do you need `tmp` at all? Say:

`fileInfo = file.split("\\.");`

and everything will work